# Azure Application Proxy CORs

Tags: azure, proxy, cors, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

Hi I am calling an Azure Application Proxy endpoint (myapp.msappproxy.net) through the browser and am running into a CORs issue.  How/where can I configure CORs for the Azure Application Proxy endpoint? I've looked in both the old and new Azure portals.

The error I'm getting is on the OPTIONS preflight request.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myapp.msappproxy.net. Response for
>   preflight is invalid (redirect)

I realize that you set the access-control headers on the API endpoint, in this case the App Proxy, but I can not find where to do so.  Additionally, I must set a custom header in my request, because am using bearer token authentication.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Nope.. I contacted the Microsoft team as well and they did not have a good answer.  We ended up moving completely away from the Azure Application Proxy.

Comment: Found a workaround. There is a limitation with the App Proxy. you can find more details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955808/cors-prelight-issue

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue. I have an **Azure Application Proxy**. So an internal page is available for externals. But normally the Application Body is set to **No**. With that setting browsers having huge **CORS** errors. To fix these CORS problems you have to set the Application Body to **Yes**. Now the body is correctly set and all browsers are able to show the website without CORS issues.

[image: application proxy settings]

Also good hints you can find in the [Enable link translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-hard-coded-link-translation#enable-link-translation) section.

Comment: I'm looking at my initial post and it was over 3 years ago! Happy that there is new functionality that enables this.